# Highchart - alternateGridColor, plot bands issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

On using alternateGridColor in the axis, existing plot band gets hidden.(color of grid is visible)

To [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotbands-events/) 
I've added the code

```
yAxis:{
    alternateGridColor: '#F5F5F5',
}
```

And the plot band disappeared. Is there anyway I can make the gridcolor in the background and plotband in the foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `zIndex` value to the relevant plotband to move the plotband forward/back in relation to the other elements. In your case, for example:

```
    xAxis: {
        plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
            // ...
            zIndex: 2
        }]
    }
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9g19pt2j/) demonstration.

The [API description](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands.zIndex) of this property:

> The z index of the plot band within the chart, relative to other elements. Using the same z index as another element may give unpredictable results, as the last rendered element will be on top. Values from 0 to 20 make sense.